# Get type of T in IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, types

This is My Generic Class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T MainModel { get; set; }

    public Type GetType()
    {
        //here
    }
}
```

Then I use it this form:

```
List<MySecondClass> Myinstance = new List<MySecondClass>();

MyClass<IEnumerable<MySecondClass>> mainInstance = new  MyClass<IEnumerable<MySecondClass>> { MainModel = Myinstance  };
```

So I need the `GetType()` Method returned `typeof(MySecondClass)` what is your suggestion?

**Update**

I must mention that always use the `MyClass` in just two form: First : I exactly coded in above and Second:

```
ThirdClass thirdone = new ThirdClass(); 
MyClass<ThirdClass> = new MyClass<ThirdClass>(){ MainModel = thirdone};
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking or actually trying to do

Comment: down vote for what? because you can't understand my question?

Comment: You want to shadow the `GetType()` function with an alternative implementation that assumes that this generic class wraps an `IEnumerable<T>`, despite a lack of constraint, and returns the type that the `IEnumerable<T>` wraps. Is that right? When all along the caller must already have this information.

Comment: and I haven't downvoted, and I'm still confused

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If `T` is `List<T>`

```
// add error checking to taste
var typeOfEnumerable = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
    .Single(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    .GetGenericArguments().First();
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/SjVpx)**.

### If `T` is `IEnumerable<T>`

```
// add error checking to taste
var typeOfEnumerable = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments().First();
```

### Important notes

You really should think about what `MyClass` is trying to do here. Why does it want to special-case for `T` being an `IEnumerable<X>`? Perhaps some constraints should be added on `T`? It's not possible to answer these and other important questions without more concrete information, but you really should do so.

Also, did you name the method `GetType` by accident or on purpose? It's *really, really, really not a good idea* to hide `object.GetType` like that, so I would suggest you rename that method.

Comment: this code rise an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: {"Sequence contains no matching element"}`

Comment: @Saeid: The code I initially gave was for `MyClass<List<T>>`, not for `MyClass<IEnumerable<T>>`. You should tell us what you are trying to do so we can suggest a good solution for all cases, otherwise as you can see errors can easily happen.

Comment: My question have the exact implementation of my usage I use `MyClass<IEnumerable<MySecondClass>>` when define an instance and I pass to the main model `List<MySecondClass>`

Comment: @Saeid: I 'm trying to say that this code does not make sense because it will break the moment you pass anything than an `IEnumerable<>` as `T`. If you are never going to do that, you should add a type parameter constraint: `class MyClass<T, X> where T : IEnumerable<X>`.

Comment: This doesn't work for Dictionaries, as their element type is KeyValuePair. If you use the GetGenericArguments().First() method, you'll just get <string> for a <string,object> dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Read too fast. Sorry about that.

```
var t = typeof(T);
if (t.IsGenericType)
{
    return t.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Won't that return `IEnumerable<MySecondClass>` in this case? You still don't have access to the underlying type, in this case, `MySecondClass`.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan Thanks for answer this is almost that I want but I think the check of `if (t.IsGenericType)` not enough in this case all of generic type included and the return type not as I want, so is there any way to check if `t is Ienumerable generic type`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `IEnumerable<T>` is used in many different cases.

Examples:

- `MyClass<IEnumerable<MySecondClass>>`: as you said, you want `MySecondClass`
- `MyClass<List<MySecondClass>>`: you probably want `MySecondClass`
- `MyClass<Dictionary<Guid, MySecondClass>>`: Also `MySecondClass`? Or `KeyValuePair<Guid, MySecondClass>`?
- `MyClass<MyOwnStringList>`: MyOwnStringList would implement `IEnumerabl<string>`. There is no generic argument on the class itself. There are many examples of that.
- `MyClass<string>`: Did you consider that string implements `IEnumerable<char>`?
- A class can implement more than one `IEnumerable<T>` definition.

After considering these cases, you have to decide what to do.

- You may search for the `IEnumerable<T>` interface and extract the generic argument. There may be more then one. There may be an exception for strings.
- You may give up trying to get the `IEnumerable<T>` generic argument.
- You may only want to support `IEnumerable<T>` directly (no subtypes) and, for instance, `IList<T>`.

Comment: you are right, maybe I couldn't explain good but I always use MyClass in 2 forms: First : I exactly coded in question, and Second:` ThirdClass thirdone = new ThirdClass(); MyClass<ThirdClass> = new MyClass<ThirdClass>(){ MainModel= thirdone};`